# How to append created elements into table

Tags: jquery, html

I have `<div id="profile">... <table>...<tbody></tbody></table> </div>`. In script I get an array of objects and iterating over that array I want to add each object's information into a table row.

```
            var $tr=$("<tr></tr>");
            var $td=$("<td></td>");
            $.each(selectedItems, function(index, obj){ //selectedItems is array of objects

                $td.html(obj.itemName);
                $tr.append($td);
                $td.html(obj.itemCount);
                $tr.append($td);
                $td.html(obj.itemPrice);
                $tr.append($td);
                $("#profile").find("table tbody").append($tr);
                $tr.empty();
                $td.empty();
            })
```

By the above code I expect each iteration will give me the following result: `<tr><td>obj.itemName</td><td>obj.itemCount</td><td>obj.itemPrice</td></tr>`. But I get nothing when I view html with google developer tools.
The selectedItems array is not empty (I checked it) and its objects are not empty too.
 What should I do to get desired result?

Comment: Be careful with the scope of your variables. You are using the same $tr and the same $td every time, emptying them every time, and changing the value every time. You should call $tr = $('<tr>') (works without the closing tag) every time you need a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use no library, so this may work:

```
var profile = document.querySelector('#profile table tbody');
var domCollection = document.createElement("div");

selectedItems.forEach(function(obj){
  var aRow = [
    obj.itemName,
    obj.itemCount,
    obj.itemPrice
  ]; // JH: 01 change their order to fullfil your wish, or add whatever you like

  var domTR = document.createElement('tr');  // JH: 02 create a <tr> element
  domTR.innerHTML = "<td>" + aRow.join('</td><td>') + "</td>" ;  // add content

  domCollection.appendChild( domTR );  // JH: 03 add this row into domCollection.
});

// JH: 04 put all rows into profile
profile.innerHTML += domCollection.innerHTML; // prevent update DOM tree too many times
```

if you like jQuery:

```
var $tmp = $('<div></div>');
$.each(selectedItems, function(index, obj){
  var aElements = [
    obj.itemName,
    obj.itemCount,
    obj.itemPrice
  ];
  var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
  $.each(aElements, function(i,str) { // append all elements into $tr
    var $td = $('<td></td>').html(str);
    $tr.append($td);
  });

  $tmp.append($tr);
});

$("#profile").find("table tbody").append($tmp.html()); // append content only once
```

Comment: in the last row instead of $tem should be $tmp

Answer (score 0):

how about this..

```
<tbody>
<% selectedItems.forEach(function(i){%>
    <tr>
         <td><%= i.itemName%></td>
         <td><%= i.itemCount%></td>
         <td><%= i.itemPrice %> \</td>

    </tr>                                           
<%});%>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Which library do you use here?

Comment: npm and ejs template